# Send "step" sensor event from ADB

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, hardware, sensors, development

My smartphone has sensors those:

```
Step Detector                                   | Qualcomm                         | 0x0000001e | on-demand         | no batching support | last=<0.000000>
Step Counter                                    | Qualcomm                         | 0x0000001f | on-demand         | no batching support | last=<0>
```

I think , when I shake phone (or when walk), Step Detector is running and send a data to applications.
If I'm right, I can send a fake event with ADB connection. But I can't find anything about this.

For example:

> adb shell sendevent StepDetector

Answer (score -1):

I had a quick look on Stack and i found this .  it might be helpful in the situation....

If you are using ADB, you will need to command into the shell with

```
adb shell        - for opening shell

su        - to gain root via superuser - Optional

sensor set acceleration 0:0:0 

sensor set acceleration 99:99:99
```

here is the references i found [StackOverflow Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361772/6116090)

Comment: Yeah, I found it too but it's for emulator. I'm working on real phone. So we can't use "sensor" command. ADB give error: "tmp-mksh: sensor: not found"

Comment: Also I tried the "SensorSimulator". The application (on phone) is connecting to the program (on pc). I'm changing accelerometer values (with random), the SensorSimilator app (on phone) see changes. But it's not real change. Just SensorSimilator can see changes. Other apps about accelerometer can't use fake values.

Comment: If you are trying to edit a specific app... Usually the last logged information is saved to data, And then opened....  If you can edit the exact shared prefs file or database ... You could just write the values to it with `echo blahblah /data/data/app-name/shared_prefs.xml` ... You will have to find the exact location, It's probably in Temp

Comment: using `sed` is better for textual replacement !

Comment: The specific app is using Server. So the app is not save datas. Just catching steps via sensors and sending to server. But the way between server and app is not HTTP. So I can't monitor datas. But if I can send sensorevent to app, app will send to server.

Comment: Just shake it :)

Comment: I can do it. Or I can put the device on a pickup player. The phone will count steps when the pickup player turns disk. :) But I want to make it via program. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only thing i can think is an Xposed module to feed fake sensor data to apps while they are being processed...